# Foreach returns only the last item

Tags: php

I'm trying to iterate an array through foreach loop, but it returns me the last item. Even if I'm setting it to global variable.  Here 's my code

```
if( !empty($product_categories) ){

    $arr = array();

    foreach ($product_categories as $key => $category) {
        $str = $category->name;
        $arr = $str;
        print_r($arr); // here I'm gettin ('cat1,cat2,cat3');
    }

    print_r($arr); // but here only 'cat3';
}
```

Could anybody tell me what is wrong with my code? Thanks.

Comment: you need to push it to an array. you are replacing same content

Comment: `$arr[] = $str;`

Comment: try this `array_push($arr, $str);`

Comment: Can I ask what the point of that loop is? I mean, you already have the category names in an array? Sure, it's an array of objects but still.

Answer (score 1):

Try this this could help. In your code each time during the loop the same variable was assigned a value. At the end of the loop the variable will have the last value in $product_categories. `$arr = $str` would mean assigning value of the variable `$str` to another variable $arr. Inorder to tell it is an array you will have to use arr[]. Hence the value is pushed into array on each loop.

```
if( !empty($product_categories) ){
    $arr = array();
    foreach ($product_categories as $key => $category) {
        $arr[] = $category->name;
        print_r($arr);
    }
    print_r($arr);
}
```

Comment: Why not remove the `$str` variable and just do `$arr[] = $category->name` directly? Also, maybe you should remove the OP's comments since it doesn't apply to your code.

Comment: You might also want to explain to OP why this would work. As it currently stands OP didn't seem to know why it didn't work, so copy pasting this response and have it magically work just means next time they have a similar issue they'll come to stack overflow for a copy-paste solution rather than actually learn anything.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Ok. Will do